# Error 000358 with SelectLayerByAttribute_managment

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I get this error when 'arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management' statement is executed. 
I tried many different ways to format my whereclause. I had printed it and it looks fine. 
But the error still there.

Anyone had similar problem?

fc_layer is a feature layer, that created in the code from a feature class in file geodatabase.

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 6, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7221, in
>   SelectLayerByAttribute     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid
>   expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

My code:

```
field1 = ['OBJECTID']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('fc_layer', field1) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         currentID = row[0]
         whereClause1 = ''' "OBJECTID" = {0} '''.format(currentID) 
         arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fc_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause1)
         arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fc_layer", "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", "fc_layer", "","ADD_TO_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
field1 = '[OBJECTID]'
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('fc_layer', "OBJECTID") as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         currentID = row[0]
         whereClause1 = field1 + '=' + currentID 
         arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fc_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause1)
         arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fc_layer", "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", "fc_layer", "","ADD_TO_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
```

With file geodatabases, the field name is called as [field], not "field" as with shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
field1 = 'OBJECTID'
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('fc_layer', field1) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         currentID = row[0]
         whereClause1 = "{0} = {1}".format(field1,currentID) 
         arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fc_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause1)
         arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fc_layer", "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", "fc_layer", "","ADD_TO_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The script worked. I had to replace UpdateCursor with SearchCursor. If I use UpdateCursor, I still get the same error message.

Comment: If that is all that you are doing with the rows in your cursor then it would make sense to use a read-only SearchCursor rather than an UpdateCursor because you appear to be doing no updating.